# How to send a request to the rest endpoint contains MultipartFile array

Tags: spring, rest, multipartform-data

We need to create a rest endpoint with MultipartFile array like below.

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
@ResponseStatus(OK) 
@RequestMapping(value = {"/v1/transform"}, method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody 
public TransformIdDTO transformFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile []  multipartFile, @RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to,final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, MessagingException {
}
```

And I want to write a testcase using HttpClient and PostMethod. I am able to send a request if MultipartFile is not array like below. I am not able to send a request if MultipartFile is array.

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod method1 = new PostMethod("URI");
Part[] parts = {new FilePart("file", f),new StringPart("from","html"),new StringPart("to","PDF")};
method1.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, method1.getParams()));
int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method1);
System.out.println(returnCode);
```

Please let me know how to send a request to the endpoint that contains MultiPartFile array.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the annotation from @RequestPart to @RequestParam and the issue resolved.